# Using variables in mathematica functions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to replicate a simple stream plot (see [this stack exchange post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147022/plotting-simple-ode-system-phase-portrait)) example using Wolfram Mathematica; however, I cannot seem to do this using variables (which is more readable). I would like the following behavior:

```js
(*What I would like to do*)
xdot = 2xy;
ydot = 1 - x^2 - y^2;
StreamPlot[
    {xdot, ydot}, 
    {x, -4, 4}, 
    {y, -4, 4}
]

(*A working code would be the following
StreamPlot[
    {2 x*y, 1 - x^2 - y^2}, 
    {x, -4, 4}, 
    {y, -4, 4}
]
*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple syntax error.

```
xdot = 2*x*y (*not 2xy*)
```

Comment: or in *Mathematica* `2 x y` with spaces.